# mvc3 and culture info for date and day names

Tags: c#

In globa.asax.cs i  use this code for cultre

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo("sl-SI");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
}
```

but when i write

`@DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek` i always get

> "Sunday"

instead of our language

> "Nedelja"

. I am using mvc3. how can i get our date and day names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DayOfWeek` is an enum, and the enum's `ToString` value will always simply give you the name of the value. You need something like:

```
string day = newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int) DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek];
```

EDIT: To make this simpler from your view, you might want a new extension method:

```
public static class DayOfWeekExtensions
{
    public static string ToCurrentCultureString(this DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        // Or CurrentUICulture... I can never remember which way round they are.
        var formatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

        return formatInfo.DayNames[(int) dayOfWeek];
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToCurrentCultureString()
```

Comment: thx for fast answers but in cshtml i dont't have newCulture variable. Can i override DayOfWeek or something else? I also need names of other days of week and months.

Comment: @senzacionale: It might make sense either to put today's date into your model for simplicity, or to create an extension method on `DayOfWeek`.

Comment: do you maybe have an example how to extend DayOfWeek method?